# How to prevent latex from entering paragraph

Tags: floats, paragraphs

I have the following problem

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{pic6}
\caption*{\textbf{Figure 4.} (left) Dielectric permittivity (\textepsilon') and (right) dielectric loss spectra (\textepsilon'') of (\textbf{8i}). Heating procedure with a step of 5 K.   }
 \end{figure}

In \textbf{Figure 4}, the dielectric permittivity and dielectric loss spectra of (\textbf{8i}) are presented.
```

The text looks correctly like this, below the figure without a paragraph gap at the beginning: [image]

When I try to do the same later on at a new figure I get a gap in the text:

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.53\textwidth]{pic7}
\caption*{\textbf{Figure 5.} Simulations of the \textalpha - process on the dielectric loss spectra at different temperatures. }
 \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic8}
\caption*{\textbf{Figure 6.} Superposition of the dielectric function \textepsilon * (top), the electric modulus \textMu * (middle) and the ionic conductivity \textsigma * (bottom) shifted to a reference temperature of 263 K.}
 \end{figure} 

The superposition of the dielectric function \textepsilon*, the electric modulus M* and the ionic conductivity is presented in \textbf{Figure 6}.
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Is this maybe because I have two consecutive figures without a text in between? And if so, how can I fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't manually number your figures, but instead use LaTeX's `\label` and `\ref` mechanism. And the first should give a new paragraph, too. Can you please post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I manually number my figures because I also use schemes but in the same environment (/begin{figure}) that way it helps me name each graph/picture/scheme the way I want it.

Comment: Why don't you create separate float environments for the other type (see the `float` package's documentation)?

Comment: The paragraph indentation occurs because there's a blank line preceding this text.  This is one of the (rare) cases where `\noindent` is appropriate.